# tikz coordinate addition in path

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

The following code:

```
\documentclass[margin = 10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (b) at (0, 1);
  \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
  \node(t) at ($(a)!0.5!(b) + (0.2, 0)$) {l};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the result:

[image]

Now, I would like to tweak the path for the node `t` by adding a displacement `(0, 0.2)` to the coordinate `a`:

```
  \node(t) at ($((a) + (0, 0.2))!0.5!(b) + (0.2, 0)$) {l};
```

How to fix this expression to conform to `tikz` `calc` rules?

Comment: Isn't it much easier to do `\draw (a) -- (b) node[midway,right,yshift=2mm] {1};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep adding nested calc syntax wherever TikZ needs to scan a coordinate or shape name.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (-1,-1) grid[step=1)] (2,2);
  \coordinate[label={[below left]:A}] (a) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate[label={[above right]:B}] (b) at (0, 1);
  \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
  % put something at (0.5, 0.5) relative to a and b
  \node[inner sep=0](t) at ($($(a) + (-1,-1)$)!0.5!($(b) + (2, 1)$)$) {.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]